# Does EF Core 5 support something like RowsetSize?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Can I use a similar feature in EF like I can in Delphi with FireDAC?

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFetchOptions.RowsetSize

Maybe if I can iterate over the results that it internally transfers the data in chunks/records?
Or do I have to wait until all of the selected data is transfered?

Comment: EF Core queries return `IEnumerable`, which by definition can be iterated (enumerated) one by one, hence no transferring of the whole result set is needed. Of course if you don't use `ToList` or similar, which would transfer everything and buffer it in memory.

Comment: No there is no need to transfer the whole result set. But without supporting these "row set fetching features" of the database it is probably done anyway.